# VBA Excel If Statement based on Text Box Entry

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I am trying to create a macro that will enable someone to type in a file name and then an email list number that will select a specific distro list. I've combined a lot of different codes online to create this.  If I were to just place an email into the ".to = " it works correctly.  But I want to implement the if statement based on which list# the person would want to send the workbook too. When I run the macro it won't send anything, which I am assuming my if statement is not working correctly.  Any advice?

```
Sub Mail_workbook_Test()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim Date1 As Date

    Date1 = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    'Date and format
    Filename = Application.InputBox("Enter File Name:", "Input Box Text", "File Name")
    'Type in File Name
    List = Application.InputBox("Enter Email List:", "Input Box Text", "List#")
    'Type in Email List
    If List = "List1" Then
    emailaddress = "email3@provider.com; email4@provider.com"
    ElseIf List = "List2" Then
    emailaddress = "email@provider.com; email2@provider.com"
    End If


    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = emailaddress
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "" + Filename + "" & " " & Date1
        .Body = "Hi Everyone," & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Please let me know if you get this!" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Thanks!"""
        .Attachments.Add ("C:\Users\Desktop\" + Filename + ".xlsx")
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of `List` after the InputBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few housekeeping items that I will comment on but not correct in your code:

1. Get rid of `On Error Resume Next`, that is potentially preventing you from seeing an error condition that might be the root cause of the failure.
2. Also, you should consider using a `FileDialog` instead of an inputbox to choose a file.  This mitigates the (very likely) chance of user error in the inputbox.

I believe, but this is not tested, that the `.To` property deals with the displayname, and according to the documentation this is the case:

> This property contains the display names only. The To property corresponds to the MAPI property PidTagDisplayTo. The Recipients collection should be used to modify this property.

So you could try this instead:

```
Dim recipient as Variant
With OutMail
    For each recipient in Split(emailaddress, ";")
        .Recipients.Add Trim(recipient)
    Next
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "" + Filename + "" & " " & Date1
    .Body = "Hi Everyone," & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Please let me know if you get this!" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Thanks!"""
    .Attachments.Add ("C:\Users\Desktop\" + Filename + ".xlsx")
    .Send   'or use .Display
End With
```

Comment: David - thank you for your input.  I am adding the MsgBox you suggested to say the list selection was not recognized.

David Z - Thank you for the input regarding the removal of the `On Error Resume Next`. I like the idea also regarding the filedialog.  I did a test run with that and I think it will be a feature I include. 

My issue right now is it doesn't recognize the distro lists after I enter which "list#" I want. Thoughts?

Comment: Can you do the mailitem `.Display` **instead** of `.Send` and let me know if you can see the email addresses in the `To` field on the email???  When I run your code and display the mail, both email addresses from the List are in the "To" field.

Comment: So I figured it out.  My coding showed

 If List = "List1" Then
    emailaddress = "email3@provider.com; email4@provider.com"
    ElseIf List = "List2" Then
    emailaddress = "email@provider.com; email2@provider.com"

Just needed to change the emailaddres to List and it worked like a charm....

thank you for the help and input.

Comment: ahhh yes, that would be an oversight in my answer. I'll revise it :)  Still curious to know why your original code did not work... it seemed to work OK for me.

Comment: Yea I don't know either. I was stumped, which made me come to here! ha  Appreciate the help as always.

Comment: David- how would you you use the FileDialog to select a file and then it be attached to an email?

Comment: Yes, I would. But you know who else would? Lots of people on this site, so it would be best to ask a new question :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to test as I don't have Outlook on my home machine, but if you suspect that it's your **If** routine where it's failing then I suggest adding an extra statement to catch a bad user entry. Here's the full **If** statement with an extra final 'Else' (meaning "if none of the previous conditions were met then do this"):

```
If List = "List1" Then
    emailaddress = "email3@provider.com; email4@provider.com"
ElseIf List = "List2" Then
    emailaddress = "email@provider.com; email2@provider.com"
Else
    MsgBox "Sorry, your list selection was not recognised."
    Exit Sub
End If
```

This will guarantee that your 'emailaddress' variable gets set correctly, OR you get a useful error message. Hope this is some help.